# Generate a large transparent GIF in PHP without using imagecreate

Tags: php, performance, gif, lzw

I need to generate a custom size transparent GIF without using imagecreate() or imagecreatetruecolor() for memory/performance reasons. 
I need the image to be as small as possible so I would like to use no GCT but only the GCE specifying the transparency so for example for a 200x200px image, like this:

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 - GIF89a
C8 00 - 200px
C8 00 - 200px
00 - No GCT
00 00 
21 F9 - Graphic Control Extension
04 01 0A 00 01 - colour #1 is transparent (I've seen this work on a 1x1 transparent GIF also without GCT)
00  - section separator
2C - image block
00 00 00 00 - block start position x=0, y=0
C8 00 C8 00 - block width and height, actually the image size
00 - section separator
? - image data follows
00 - section separator
3B - image end
```

So far I can generate the above GIF structure but the part where I'm stuck is where I need to create the LZW encoded data.
For the 1x1 transparent pixel image which works, I've seen these bytes are as follows:

```
02 - LZW minimum code size
02 - LZW data length
4C 01 - actual LZW data
```

First, I have doubts in understanding how this gets decoded. Does this mean that the LZW mapping table has 3 bit codes? If so, how does it map to bytes?

Can anyone explain or provide a code snippet which would generate the LZW data for an arbitrary width x height transparent GIF?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I kept the block as a 1x1 transparent block, which is valid and works in all browsers.
With this approach you also need to keep the block sizes to 1 x 1 like this:

```
2C - image block
00 00 00 00 - block start position x=0, y=0
01 00 01 00 - block width and height, actually the image size
```